# Strange Bug with View's Frame Becoming (0,0,0,0) While Doing UI Layout in Xcode?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode6.1

I have one textView and one imageView into my ViewController and when I try to stretch textView or imageView from the corner the other View's width, height and position become (0,0) like this

[image: gyazo.com/4b07f8066a810d9cb9ac1f138baff001]

And I also tried this too.

[image: gyazo.com/aeb0c9a8e9cd3c74e1f41208801fbb49]

I don't understand what is the problem here and my Xcode Version is 6.1 (6A1052d)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That was a bug in Xcode 6.1 caused if there were not constraints set. Use Xcode 6.1.1(6A2008a) instead.
You could also add the missing constraints to it(add missing constraints from the constraints-menu) to workaround that bug.

But as I said, the problem is solved in Xcode 6.1.1